# 0 discovered links in Google Search Console and only my homepage is indexed

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, next.js

Last month I launched my website.
It is using SSR, fixed almost all high/medium priority SEO issues existing in screaming frog, all pages are indexable and SEO friendly and from my index page I have a lot of internal links.
I do not have a no-index meta and my robots.txt is fine.

Google didn't discover my website, I had to request indexing of my homepage and I waited for 1 month and google didn't at least crawl any other pages.
[image: Search console image]

Searching for `site:dansador.com` there is only my index page (which is also manually requested to be indexed)

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for Google to take its time to index the first page.  And then a bit more time to index other pages.

You can speed up the process by using `URL Inspection` and adding the pages in and asking for indexing.  It will tell you at that time, what (if any) problem there is with it.

From my experience, if you ask Google to index the site too early and there are pages with errors, then It doesn't appear to crawl those pages again.  (It does crawl them, once the site has existed for a while - trusted).  In this case, asking the URLs to be indexed, as above, fixes it.

Finally, you may think that the pages are fine,  but there may be errors or inconsistencies that Google does not like. Use one of the many sites to check your website.  I use Ahrefs.  I am not associated with it.